# How to extract data from excel file into database with dynamic file name SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

Can you guy please help?

I have a problem to load data from excel into database with dynamic file name in my source files.

For example, for this month, my filename is ABC 31122017.xlsx. I successfully loaded data from each tab in this excel file into database.

But how do I make it dynamic? For example next month I have excel file 
ABC 31012018.xlsx. How to make the job dynamic to pick up the new file?

I able to put the date in variable, but I don't know how to proceed with the filepath in SSIS.

```
@[User::InputPath] + "ABC " +  @[User::Report_DT_DDMMYYYY] + ".xlsx"
```

I used this in Expressions in the Connection already, set up ExcelFilePath, but it couldn't work.

As in Excel Source connector in SSIS, I already chose the 31122017.xlsx and chose the first tab. But after I put in the Expressions, it couldn't find the first tab I chosen already.

Please help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: If that is the only file in that directory that starts with "ABC " then I would use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

May be below explanation will help you in overcome this issue (I have SSIS 2012) -

1. First SSIS variable will hold date value i.e., "20180218". Variable Name- TodayDate. This variable value will be change according to today date.
2. Second SSIS variable will hold FileName i.e., ""D:\SSIS\StackOverFlowTest1\InputFiles\AB " + @[User::TodayDate]  + ".xlsx". Variable Name- FileNameExcel.
3. Create connection manager for excel and under its properties window change expressions and set ExcelFilePath to "FileNameExcel".[image]
4. Change "Delay Validation" to True under "Data Flow Task" property.[image]

Comment: In my experience, you are not getting the file on a specific date (especially today). It is usually back dated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a foreach:

1. Set up a string variable fileName (put in the actual file path / file name so you can develop your package.
2. Add a Foreach Loop (File Enumerator which is default)
3. Set Expression for Directory = @InputPath
4. Set Files to the proper mask for your excel file (i.e. "ABD *.xlsx")
5. Go to variable mappings and link to fileName
6. Add an Excel connection and connect to your actual file.
7. Set an expression on properties to ExcelFilePath = @fileName
8. Delay Validation
9. Develop your data flow(s) as normal.